# Как удалить из двумерного вектора числа кратные 10 и 7 С++

Tags: c++, vector

подскажите как удалить из двумерного вектора числа кратные 10 и 7 с использованием erase, то есть через итераторы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему именно `erase`? Не проще так?

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto i){ return i%10==0 || i%7==0; }),v.end());
```